# Do I need anything other than a passport when traveling through Canada?

Tags: visas, airports

I am a US Citizen, traveling to France later this year.  I have a 7 hour layover in Montreal, Canada.  Do I need any other documents, other than my passport when stopping in Canada?

Comment: Vaccination booklet, if you've got one?

Comment: @MarkMayo A vaccination booklet for a US citizen going to France via Canada? Why would proof of vaccinations be required for that trip?

Comment: @ZachLipton not from France, but if he's been anywhere else say French territories in Africa. I was literally just trying to think of anything else that might be requested.

Comment: I think it's better to say that having a valid Passport is the *minimum* required for a US Citizen to enter Canada.

Answer (score 5):

As a US citizen, you should not need anything other than a passport in the situation you described - you can verify this [here](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm). Of course, this assumes that the Canadian immigration officer believes you - in case there is any suspicion, be prepared to show proof that your intention is just transit (ticket for onwards travel to France, etc) - but realistically it shouldn't be a problem unless there's something about you that the immigration officer finds suspicious. There may be some special requirements in some special circumstances, e.g. if you have a criminal record you may need additional documents.

Comment: Since US citizens can enter Canada for tourist and business purposes it shouldn't matter even if the immigration officer thinks you are not flying on to France.

Comment: @DJClayworth If the immigration person thinks the visitor has, for example, intent to stay and work in Canada they will not be admitted. There is no right of entry for anyone but Canadian citizens (and maybe certain refugees or other protected classes).

Answer (score 1):

[For a US citizen no.](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-result.asp?country=US&result=3&q3=)  You need only your passport.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. It is good practice to provide a summary or short excerpt of the information behind a link, in case it goes bad (as governmental sites very often do). I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.